# Improper code for _byteswap_uint64() with clang-cl

Tags: visual-c++, clang

If I use the _byteswap_uint64() intrinsic of MSVC with the mostly MSVC compatible compiler clang-cl the code generates a call to the external library function _byteswap_uint64() which does the well known mask and shift orgy. Whith MSVC I simply get a x86 BSWAP instruction which is there since the 486 so there shouldn't be any processor optimization level relevant here. clang-cl understands a lot of command line options MSVC doesn't understand, even -march=native. So if I have -march=native the code is still a call to the mentioned function.
I use clang-cl 13 through the IDE (installed from the Visual Studio installer).
Is there a way to get proper code like with MSVC ?

Answer (score 0):

I've got it. Simply use the clang specific intrinsics with conditional compilation:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <intrin.h>

uint64_t swapThis( uint64_t value )
{
#if defined(__llvm__)
    return __builtin_bswap64( value );
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
    return _byteswap_uint64( value );
#endif
}
```

**clang**_ isn't defined with clang-cl under Windows but only with clang++ under Windows, so I had to use _*llvm*.